# Mark multiple maps for download at once?

Tags: 8.0, lumia, maps, here

I have a Nokia Lumia 620.

I would like to download all of europe to have for offline use.

On my Symbian phone I could mark all maps via the Nokia Suite at once for download and it would then download them one after the other without me having to do anything. (I could do this overnight.)

On first glance, it seems that with Nokia Maps / HERE on this WP8 device, I'll have to start a download for each individual map *and then wait for the download to complete* before I'm able to download another map.

Given the size of the maps, this'll take me a month. (1-2 maps per evening where I can start this and leave the download running in my home WIFI.)

Am I missing something?

Comment: Sounds more like a size/bandwidth issue, rather than a multiple download issue? Running two concurrent downloads will (roughly) half the speed of each, so that the net finish time remains the same.

Comment: @RowlandShaw - Of course its a size issue! All maps of europe have approx 5GB+ - that's going to take hours and hours on any normal connection. But if I can't tell the phone to start downloading them all (*one after the other*), I will have to start another download after having to wait for the previous multi 100MB download to finish!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, you're not missing anything. The UI won't let you do this...

There is a work around, though. Start the download of one region, then tap "cancel" in the app bar. Then, start the download of another region. You'll notice a message asking whether to resume the first download. If you tap "not now" you can go and add another region to download.

When you've selected all the regions, you can resume and it will download all those selected simultaneously.

Comment: Nice. This works halfway. However, one needs to wait for each new download to at least have started. (If you interrupt it in the "preparing" state, it will not be resumed.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are missing something. Tap the circle with three checkmarks and horisontal lines at the bottom of the country list. Now you can select multiple countries and then download them at once. However, you can't mix whole countries and regions of big countries.